# 8086 Assembly with AFD error but emu8086 everything fine why?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

When I'm running this code in emu8086 everything is fine, but I have to run this code in AFD and when then line after line im tipping I have a error in `JC et2`

> Symbol not defined

[image]

```
MOV CL,00fh
MOV SI,000h
MOV DI,000h

;i=0    
MOV [220h+SI],240h

et1:        
MOV AH,[210h+DI]
INC DI
MOV AL, [210h+DI]  
CMP AH,AL
JC et2   

INC SI
INC SI              
MOV [220h+SI],240h

loop et1 

HLT    

et2:      
INC SI
INC SI
DEC CL
JNZ et1
HLT     
loop et2  

ret
```

Please help me handle that

Comment: AFD doesn't support referencing a label that hasn't been defined yet. You put `jc et2` in but you haven't reached a point of defining `et2` so you get an undefined symbol. What you can do is temporarily put a place holder in for the branch target. I'd just do `jc $`. Now continue on entering the code. Once you define label `et2` go back and replace `jc $` with `jc et2`

Comment: What program is this running inside of DOSBox?

Answer (score 0):

It seems very hard to find info about "AFD" but here are some pointers that might help you find a solution:

- If you're submitting this program to "AFD" as source, then it could be that the mnemonic `jc` is simply not understood. Try using `jb` which does exactly the same.
- Different programs have different sets of reserved words. Maybe "AFD" considers *et2* a reserved symbol rendering the instruction `jc et2` meaningless. Try renaming your labels. Perhaps choose *IsBelow* ? Anyway , using more meaningful names is always a good idea.

---

A few remarks on your code:

- You only initialize the CL register with `MOV CL,00fh`. Note that the `loop` instruction depends on the entire CX register.
- The `loop et2` instruction below the `hlt` makes no sense! If it got executed at all, it would start a 64KB loop (because the counter would be 0 at that time) destroying your program data altogether.

---

Since all that you really do when AH is below AL is bypass the writing of another number 0240h, you can nicely simplify your progran like this:

```
    MOV  CX, 000Fh
    MOV  SI, 0000h
    MOV  DI, 0000h
    MOV  [0220h+SI], 0240h
TopOfTheLoop:
    MOV  AH, [0210h+DI]
    INC  DI
    MOV  AL, [0210h+DI]
    INC  SI
    INC  SI
    CMP  AH, AL
    JB   IsBelow
    MOV  [0220h+SI], 0240h
IsBelow:
    LOOP TopOfTheLoop
    HLT
```

Comment: The loop et2 is used as if statement because when I wrote without loop error appeard. In your code is flaw  undeclared label: LOOP MyLabel1

Comment: @CezaryCzekalski You're right, I changed my code a few times and forget this one! My bad. Also, did you try any of my suggestions and did it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, to solve my problem you have to define et2:...loop et2 and then write JC et2. 
if et2 is not defined you cannot use JC et2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to solve my problem you have to define et2:...loop et2 and then write JC et2. 
if et2 is not defined you cannot use JC et2.